# If no one holds reference to a CompletableFuture, will it always be completed before being garbage collected?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, future, completable-future

A java object is eligible for garbage collection once unreachable, my confusion is what happens to unreachable CompletableFutures like this:

```
void someMethod(){
     methodThatProduceCompletableFuture()
          .thenAccept(s -> //produce some side effect);
}
```

call to someMethod may return before the CompletableFuture is completed, as no one holds reference to the CompletableFuture, will this CompletableFuture be garbage collected before its completion?

Comment: There is a live reference to the `CompletableFuture` inside its own `thenAccept()` until the future completes and `thenAccept()` returns, so no GC until then.

Comment: You are asking the wrong question. Your actual question is “Will ‘*produce some side effect*’ get executed?”, regardless of the `CompletableFuture` instance not visible inside that function.

Answer (score 0):

#### The answer to your question

The answer to your question as it's worded, "If no one holds reference to a CompletableFuture, will it always be completed before being garbage collected?" is no, it will never be completed. If no one holds a reference to the CompletableFuture, it's not possible for someone to call `complete()` on said future.

#### The answer to your intended question (presumably)

I don't think that's the intent of your question, though. Let me guess the intended context and rephrase it:

"If I, with my code, don't explicitly reference a CompletableFuture, will it be completed before being garbage collected?"

The answer here is, depends. Let's use your example.

```
void someMethod(){
     methodThatProduceCompletableFuture()
          .thenAccept(s -> //produce some side effect);
}
```

Focusing on `methodThatProduceCompletableFuture()` first, if all this method does is create an empty future --

```
CompletableFuture<Boolean> methodThatProduceCompletableFuture() {
    return new CompletableFuture<>();
}
```

then this will be Garbage Collected before completion. No one holds a reference to the returned future. Because of this, it's both eligible for Garbage Collection **and** there's no way for it to be completed.

However, if you implement it like this --

```
CompletableFuture<Boolean> methodThatProduceCompletableFuture() {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> someJobThatReturnsBoolean());
}
```

this is a different story. It may look similar to the first implementation, but the key difference here is this implementation will **spawn a thread that references the future**. Once that job completes, it will call `complete()` on this future we're returning. That's the reference that will keep this future alive.

And that's basically it. `thenAccept()` may seem different at first, but then you realize the CompletableFuture produced by `methodThatProduceCompletableFuture()` has to hold a reference to this future, in order for it to run when the first future completes. The answer, then, boils down to whether `methodThatProduceCompletableFuture()` produces a CompletableFuture that has a reference to it and will complete.

#### Addendum 1

I fudged my usage of "is referenced" and "will complete" a bit at times, to avoid overcomplicating things. There's a difference. If an object is "referenced", it won't be Garbage Collected. But just because it won't be Garbage Collected, doesn't mean it "will complete". That's up to the operations passed into the CompletableFuture.

And as mentioned in the beginning, if an object is not referenced it's not possible for it to be completed, because of lack of access to the `complete()` function.

#### Addendum 2

In a way, the answer to this question is "don't think about it". If your CompletableFuture is written so that it will complete, then that means someone, somewhere holds a reference to your future and will complete it.

Even in the `new CompletableFuture<>()` case above, as long as you passed that future somewhere and someone plans to complete it, then your chain of operations is safe.